# What's the best practice with channels (RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, publish, channel

I have an app in which for each received message it publishes N in the same channel. I'm wondering whether it'd be better to have two channel, a Publish channel and a Receive channel.

What would it be the best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice is to have one channel per consumer/ queue.  I would say that would extend to publishing on a different channel as consuming.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the above answer, channels are essentially cost-free.  A "channel" in RabbitMQ is just an integer that is tacked on to the raw packet indicating what channel it is for.  The underlying TCP stream is still the same.  There is a negligible additional amount of resources consumed by keeping track of all the different channels on the client and server side, but this is really only a problem if you are creating close to the maximum number of channels.